# $10 − 2 + 0.4 - 0.08 + \cdots$· converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine whether the following are convergent or divergent. If it is
convergent find its sum. Make sure to fully justify all of your work.

2/10 = 1/5, which happens to be the common ratio. According to geometric series test since r is less than 1 we know it converges.

My problem is, I don't know how to check if r = 1/5, or -1/5.

If its r = -1/5, the sum is 25/3, if its r = 1/5 the sum is 25/2

Comment: here  $r = -1/5.$.

Comment: the signs alternate so its -1/5

Comment: Think of it as $10+(-2)+0.4+(-0.08)+\cdots$. A geometric series is a sum. Then the ration of the consecutive terms is $-1/5$.

Comment: Alternatively, the value is less than $10$, so it can't be $25/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you find that difficult or confusing then we can have this way

Approach 1 -

$|r| < 1$ is required for the geometric series to converge implying your series converges and you can find the sum by using $s = \frac{a}{1- r}$ , $a$ is the first term in your series.

> In your answer $25/3$ is the correct one , for simple intuition as provided in the comments, the sum cannot exceed 10 so it cannot be $25/2$ so only choice remaining is $25/3$.

Approach 2 -

Another way is this which helps in proving the series is converging. Intuition - If something bigger converges then the smaller thing converges too! (Comparision test for series convergence)-

Better find the absolute value sum and if it converges then surely the given series converges.

see that $10 - 2 + 0.4 - 0.08 + ... <  10 + 2 + 0.4 + 0.08 + ...$
and the right side sum is convergent as it is a geometric series with $r = 0.2$ which is $r < 1$ and hence since absolute series converges , the original series also converges!

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch the signs.  The ratio of the first two terms is $\frac {-2}{10}=-\frac 15$.  The ratio of every other pair that we can see is the same.  The signs are important.